# Ignore JSON Field only when executing a POST

Tags: jakarta-ee, swagger, resteasy

I have a Resteasy + Swagger application which contains the following POST action:
[image]
My issue is that the "id" field should not be included in the POST method, as it's generated by a DB Sequence.
On the other hand, the "id" field must be included if I attempt to modify an existing Order with a PUT method.
Therefore I cannot simply add a **@JsonIgnore** annotation to the id field.
Is there a strategy to produce the example JSON POST method without the id field?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't think it's a duplicate. I'm not choosing between GET and POST but between POST and PUT. I assume that both POST and PUT are write operations.

Comment: Have you considered including ID in the endpoint path for PUT? E.g. `POST /things` to create a new thing but `PUT /things/{id}` to modify a thing. (Or in your example - something like `POST /customers/{custId}/orders` vs `PUT /customers/{custId}/orders/{orderId}`.) This way the ID won't be in the request body.